# nginx proxy_pass configuration for two services running on diff ports

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I need to redirect or proxy_pass the following:

Every request starting with `/api/v1/` to: `@server`
everything else `/` to `@client`

I have `@server` running on port `8080` and `@client` on port `8081`
`@client and @server` are running as docker containers.

Note. Everything should be using https.
The following config is what I have but its not working idkw

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    ...

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location /api/v1/ {
        try_files $uri @server;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @client;
    }

    location @client {
        proxy_pass http://client:8081;
    }

    location @server {
        proxy_pass http://server:8080/api/v1/;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Could you be more specific on what's working improperly in your setup?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov My setup is not working. What am I doing wrong would be the question

Answer (score -2):

If you *must* use named locations then you can use `error_page` approach below.

By `return`ing *unused* HTTP status codes and `error_page` for those codes set to  named locations, we can forward requests to those named locations:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    ...

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    error_page 350 = @client;
    error_page 351 = @server;

    location /api/v1/ {
        return 351;
    }

    location / {
        return 350;
    }

    location @client {
        proxy_pass http://client:8081;
    }

    location @server {
        proxy_pass http://server:8080/api/v1/;
    }

}
```

Comment: Danila, Thanks for your answer but probably there are better approaches to fix this. Actually, `@client` and `@server` are known hosts, so there is no need to redirect to them as error pages.

Comment: I think my solution is the only feasible if you require using those named locations. If not, then obviously you can just put `proxy_pass`-es directly directly into `/` and `/api/v1/` (while removing named locations altogether). Otherwise you can use third party module `echo` (have a look at `echo_exec` directive). And finally there is no actual errors with `error_page`. In fact, It is only a directive name for handling specific HTTP status codes.